# Displaying degrees of separation in real time strategy

Tags: mysql, php-5.3

I have a site that allows users to "connect" to one another by following eachother. The site needs to display statistics such as "You have X mutual followers" or "You are following X mutual people". Until now, this calculation has been processed in real time, but now we have too many users to calculate this in real time in a timely manner.

I'm considering options to cache or otherwise enhance the performance of this calculation, but before I do so I realize that there may already exist a common approach to this problem that may solve it in a simpler manner before I over-engineer this myself.

Technology used: PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.5, nginx, and a Linux environment.

Comment: How many users do you have? As this can be done with two joins I think you must be doing something wrong to hit performance issues.

Comment: On the pages that this calculation occurs, it is displayed multiple times -- for example, you see an index of people and the calculation occurs for each person on the page. The amount of users is over 20k. The query is currently done with a simple join or two, I don't think the issue is the SQL query.

Comment: first you should check your query - it should be very fast, if it’s not, something is wrong. If it is fast and performance only suffers because it’s run to often, caching is the way to go. Just cache in your database or somewhere else and invalidate the cache, when the relevant data changes.

Comment: The query is fine from a performance perspective, but when calculating this many times per page load, at peak times, it becomes a bottleneck for the app. I've proposed a caching solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that you do not change the list of friends from a lot of places nor very frequently. So there you have an easy way of invalidating the cache when necessary. Create a table with 4 rows: `id1, id2, num, date`, and set indexes on id1, id2 and date. Now cache your data using the method in your answer, but you need to delete old entries yourself if you want that to happen. Just add something like this:

```
if rand(1, 100) == 1:
    SQL(DELETE FROM cache WHERE date < now - ***)
```

Also make sure that id1 < id2, to avoid duplicates in your cache.

When the friends list of a user changes, delete all cache-entries that are connected to that user. This way your numbers will always be up to date.

If you don’t care if the numbers might be a little bit of, your solution is fine – just normalize $key, so that id1 < id2.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach to this problem is simply using a cache layer stored in memory (probably using memcache)

When a user views a page that contains these statistics, check the cache to see if the stats already exist. If they do not, calculate the number of mutual connections and store the user ID's as a hash for the cache key.

**Example in PHP, somewhat psuedo-code:**

```
// Fred = User ID #47, George = User ID #94

$key = md5('47,94');

// Check that cache key is valid

if ($cache->isValid($key)) {
    return $cache->get($key);
} else {
    // ..calculate mutual connections
    $cacheTime = time() + (60 * 60 * 6);
    $value = calculateMutualConnections(array(47,94));
    $cache->save($key,$value,$cacheTime);
    return $value;
}
```

This would store the cached value for 6 hours. Not sure if that's sufficient enough time or not. I believe this approach would work, but may not be as real time as I'd like.